# How can I correct the expectation formula?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $p_i$ be probability a packet sends from a client $i^{th}$ to a server will be lost. I have two clients which will send packet to the server. The first client will send $n_1$ packets, with loss probability  $p_1$ and the second client will send $n_2$ packet, with loss probability $p_2$

It is easy to compute the expected number of packet can reaches to the server as $(1-p_1)n_1+(1-p_2)n_2$

However, I do not know how can I represent the expectation number of packets at the server by using mathematic form. is it right if I write as follows:

$E(X)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)=(1-p_1)n_1+(1-p_2)n_2$

where $X_i$ is event that sends packet from client $i^{th}$ to the server

Comment: What exactly are the possible outcomes here? Either $n_{i}$ packets arrive or $0$ arrive, right? The former with probability $1 - p_{i}$. If that's what you have in mind, then your calculation is correct. It's misleading to call $X_{i}$ an event, though. $X_{i}$ is a random variable whose value is the number of packets that arrive.

Comment: In this question, I do not know how can I represent the expected number to the server. It is main purpose of my question. I think the result is not so matter

Comment: I was just asking you to be clearer about what you're trying to model. The expected value you give is correct if the situation is that the $i^{th}$ client sends $n_{i}$ packets and either all $n_{i}$ arrive or none do. And your notation is fine, with the caveat that $X_{i}$ is a random variable, not an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, exactly so.

We may let $X_i$ be a *random variable* counting the number of packets that arrive among the $n_i$ sent from server$\#~i$.   For two servers the total is $X=X_1+X_2$.

Since each has a binomial distribution, $X_i\sim\mathcal {Bin}(n_i, 1-p_i)$, then the expectation of each is $\mathsf E(X_i)=n_i(1-p_i)$.

Finally, for the expectation of the total we use the law of total expectation, so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)~=~&\mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_2)
\\ =~& n_1(1-p_1)+n_2(1-p_2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank Graham Kemp for the clear answer. Before I see your answer, I do that "Is it possible to use notation $X$" for my task? Finally, we can said that $X$ is a random variable counting the number packet that reaches to server. Is it right? Because you did not mention about notation $X$